# Computer Science Education

Tags: education

Hello everyone i'm from Turkey and i'm 18 years old. I'll get university exam after a month. I want Computer Science department. But there is only one department for it and this department's score is very very higher than i can do. I wanna carier about Quantum Engineering and according to my research i need get Computer Science department. I really wanna do somethings real for Computer Science and for future. Is there another way to get Computer Science Education?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: At 18 years, I expect you to have overcome *wanna*.

Comment: Maybe you can talk to someone at the university? I think that many professors like to see enthusiastic students succeed. Although, if your score is very low, maybe you just cannot do it until your score is higher.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/196012/705